# Export orders with addresses in xml

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, csv, shipping-address, export

I have a problem with a Magento ver. 1.9.4.5 website with well over 55.000 customers in it's database and I need to export them. I have spent hours trying with System/export/profile and selecting Customer and all the mapping fields. The problem is that the customers do not have the "address" saved in their profile, but i see it visible in the Order itself as the shipping address.

Now I need to export the orders with the client name and shipping address into an XML. The orders export button from the Orders tab exports only the State, i need the full address.

I need to mention that i do not have acces in the back-end of the website, just the admin user for Magento.